# Owin StartWebApp access denied after netsh http all url

Tags: c#, windows, owin, katana

I saw a lot on this matter but everything provided the same answer.
I still can't make it work.

The application uses port 8080.
I executed via Administrator console:

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:8080/ user=Everyone
```

Also deleted and tried to add, specifying my user:

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:8080/ user=MyUser
```

And verified the port is free using:

```
netstat -an | findstr 8080
```

Which gave no results.

I'm starting my app via console (not with 'Run as Administrator') and can't get past 'Access denied' error.

When I 'Run as Administrator' everything works perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I found the problem thanks to [Frends R&D Blog](https://frendsrnd.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/httpselfhostserver-hosted-web-api-with-https-and-windows-authentication-enabled/).
It mentions the configured url and the netsh command url must be exactly the same.

In my code the url was configured:

```
http://*:8080/
```

While in my netsh command i used

```
http://+:8080
```

Once I changed in my code to use '+' instead of '*' everything worked.